# Full Screen Scrolling in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

Is there any library which will provide us full screen scrolling in iOS app like Facebook Application. On Scrolling navigation bar got hide and only status bar will be showing when we scroll up and when we starts down scrolling then navigation bar starts showing. I want this functionality in complete Swift Code. If possible then please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the Facebook Application, iOS includes a way to automatically hide the Navigation Bar natively.

From the `ViewController` in which you have a `TableView`/`ScrollView`, you can set your Navigation bar to automatically hide on swipe by calling

`self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true`

Now, assuming your tableView is populated enough to let the user scroll down, the Navigation Bar should hide when the user scrolls through it! The status bar will show the same color as the Navigation Bar, as you requested. It will also show again when the user scrolls back up the list.

Comment: Hi Chris,

This code hides us both status bar and navigation bar. I don't want to hide status bar on scroll. I just want to hide navigation bar. One thing more is there any way to change the colour of status bar when scrolling up and re change the colour of status bar on scrolling down. If yes then please let me know and thanks a lot :)

Comment: You could add a `UIView` on top of the Navbar and change its color when you start swiping. Just make the `UIView` the same color as the NavigationBar so that you can't see it until the bar hides?